# Getting the encoding of a Postgres database

Tags: postgresql

I have a database, and I need to know the default encoding for the database. I want to get it from the command line.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

From the command line:

```
psql my_database -c 'SHOW SERVER_ENCODING'
```

---

From within `psql`, an SQL IDE or an API:

```
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
```

Comment: Isn't that the server-level setting (the default used for newly created databases) rather than the database/catalog-level setting asked for in the Question?

Comment: Note that from within psql, there needs to be a semicolon at the end. i.e.


`SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;`

Answer (score 65):

Method 1:

If you're already logged in to the db server, just copy and paste this.

```
SHOW SERVER_ENCODING;
```

Result:

```
  server_encoding 
-----------------  
UTF8
```

For Client encoding :

```
 SHOW CLIENT_ENCODING;
```

Method 2:

Again if you are already logged in, use this to get the list based result

```
\l
```

Answer (score 50):

A programmatic solution:

```
SELECT pg_encoding_to_char(encoding) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'yourdb';
```

Answer (score 34):

If you want to get database encodings:

```
psql  -U postgres -h somehost --list
```

You'll see something like:

```
List of databases
           Name         |  Owner   | Encoding
------------------------+----------+----------
db1                     | postgres | UTF8
```

Answer (score 15):

## tl;dr

```
SELECT character_set_name 
FROM information_schema.character_sets 
;
```

## Standard way: `information_schema`

From the [SQL-standard schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html) present in every database/catalog, use the defined view named [`character_sets`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-character-sets.html). This approach should be portable across [all standard database systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema#Implementation).

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.character_sets 
;
```

Despite the name being plural, it shows only a single row, reporting on the current database/catalog.

[image: screenshot of pgAdmin 4 with results of query shown above]

The third column is `character_set_name`:

> Name of the character set, currently implemented as showing the name of the database encoding

Answer (score 13):

Because there's more than one way to skin a cat:

```
psql -l
```

Shows all the database names, encoding, and more.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of getting the server encoding (described at https://pgpedia.info/s/server_encoding.html):

```
 SELECT current_setting('server_encoding');
```

One can also use a similar select to get other settings, e.g. 'client_encoding'.