# how make application accept any language in input field and store as it is in database

Tags: java, utf-8, input-field

I have developed Application with Java and Spring MVC.
Here, My issue is my application form input field is accepting any language but it is stored it as a different text not exactly as I've typed. English is properly inserted, other than English no other language is not properly inserted.
So, In the form input field, I want to accept any language and store that language as it is in database.
can anyone please tell me, what changes should I have to do in jsp page.
My charset is in utf-8

Comment: Which database are you using? You might have to check the character set used in the database aswell

Comment: @leonardseymore I've using PostgreSQL and datatype varchar

Comment: Can you check the db charset? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454146/getting-the-encoding-of-a-postgres-database

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
Map<String, String> queryMap = HttpMessage.parseRequestParameters(request.messageBody);

URLDecoder.decode(queryMap.get("htmlObject"),StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
```