# Postgres DB connection to FastAPI

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, character-encoding, psycopg2

I'm trying to connect a postgres DB with fastapi. My postgres DB is a docker contanier. My docker-compose is:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgres/data/

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5050
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    depends_on:
      - postgres


volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

and in `databases.py` is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()
```

My `main.py` is:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from databases.database import Base, engine


def create_tables():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

create_tables()

app = FastAPI()

version = "v0.1"

# Import routers

# Add CORS
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"detail": "Backend working on"}
```

If I change `localhost` to `postgres`, I have an error that is:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Unknown host`

but... with `localhost` I recieve the next problem:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte`

Complete error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 76, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 61, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 68, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 467, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    create_tables()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\main.py", line 8, in create_tables
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 5828, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3242, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3232, in begin
    with self.connect() as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3268, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 145, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3292, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 452, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 1269, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 716, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 169, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 167, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 393, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 678, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 902, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 898, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 637, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 616, in connect
    return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\UNI\5ºAño\TFG\tfg_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte
```

Versions:

- sys version: `'3.11.6 (tags/v3.11.6:8b6ee5b, Oct  2 2023, 14:57:12) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)]'`
- `SQLAlchemy==2.0.23`
- `psycopg2==2.9.9`

Comment: Strange - there seems to be something in the connection parameters that psycopg2 receives, _or_ the response it gets from the server - that is not properly encoded. Can you connect via PgAdmin? Can you view the [client and server encoding settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16434925/5320906)?

Comment: It looks like you have pgAdmin_4 available. Can you use it to check the encoding setting for your database? FWIW, mine looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYRDL.png).

Comment: I have checked the properties and it's all correct. All are in UTF-8

Comment: From a Python interactive prompt (`>>>`) try `import psycopg2` followed by `conn = psycopg2.connect(database="postgres", user="postgres", password="postgres", host="localhost")` - does that throw an error?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and I receive the same error (`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 85: invalid continuation byte`), it could be the enconding of the project?

Comment: To be clear you are attempting to connect from the host OS to the Postgres instance in the Docker image, correct? If so **add to your question** the host OS and version. Also add the SQLAlchemy and psycopg2 versions. Best bet is you are having issues with Windows character set.

Comment: Again, at the Python `>>>` prompt, `import sys` followed by `sys.version` - please show the entire output.

Comment: Added versions and the sys.version print to the problem

Comment: You have not indicated the host OS and version. Also what character set the host OS is using.